# Join a table with a specific condition

Tags: postgresql, hibernate

I have three tables:
"user" who has one or more rows associated with him in the "contractYear" table, which consists of rows in a "contract_month" table.

I want to get the result set of users who do not have contract months for the current contract year (i.e. contract Year.endDate < current date)

I made the following query:

```
@Query("select distinct u "
        + " from User u "
        + " left join u.contractYears cy"
        + " on cy.endDate < now()"
        + " left join cy.contractMonths cm"
        + " where cm is null")
```

But it doesn't work...

I assume the condition `"on cy.endDate < now()"` is not correct.

Maybe someone can help me make the correct query?

Comment: *But it doesn't work...* are you getting incorrect results or an error?

Comment: @M Khalid Junaid, I get an incorrect result: I get all users who have the current contract year. I am assuming the "where cm is null" condition is ignored.

Comment: `user` is a reserved name in Postgres. Better not use it as a (table or column) identifier.

Comment: I apologize for forgetting about this. In real case, my table is called a little differently. i used the name "user" just for example

Answer (score 2):

In HQL if you need additional filter in join clause you can add using `WITH` keyword

```
select distinct u 
from User u 
left join u.contractYears cy
     with cy.endDate < now()
left join cy.contractMonths cm
where cm is null
```

[See 14.3. Associations and joins section](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/queryhql.html)